# How are "campsite" and "campground" used in American English?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology, american-english

A common word for a place used for staying overnight outdoors would be "campground" in AmE and "campsite" in BrE. However, I learned that Americans also use the word "campsite." 
My questions is to what extent, and are both terms used interchangeably?

Or maybe there is a difference with regard to the following meanings:
    an impromptu area (as one might decide to stop while backpacking or hiking);
    a dedicated area with improvements and various facilities

or maybe it depends more on the region of the US where the term is used?

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=campsite%2Ccampground&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccampsite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccampground%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccampsite%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccampground%3B%2Cc1) displayed this:[image]

so I can imagine both terms are pretty common.
I am directing this question mainly to AmE native speakers. How do you feel about both terms?

Comment: You arrive at the campground and check in.  You set up your tent at your assigned campsite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done a lot of camping over the years: backpacking, car camping, off-highway vehicles (Land Rovers), etc.

A ***campsite*** is where you camp.  The place where you pitch your tent or park your vehicle. In a more developed area, it's likely to have a picnic table and fire ring and be fairly well defined.

A ***campground***, on the other hand, is a group of such sites.  A single campground may have a few campsites or it may have hundreds.  It could also be used to refer to a group of campsites within a single park or area.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In that case the term "campsite" has a different meaning to the one we use in Britain. Here a "campsite" is the entire field or ground. Now you are going to ask me what we call an individual place on that site. And I am struggling to give you an answer - perhaps a "tent site", or "parking place".

Comment: @WS2 We'd call the individual sites 'pitches'

Comment: @Spagirl Absolutely right. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: In a US campground, a *pitch* is where you throw horseshoes. It's a bad place to put up your tent.